# Updating Every Row With select concatenate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that I want to update a column in the whole thing.  I have this for the concatenation.

```
(COALESCE(f1,'')+';'+ COALESCE(f2,'')+';'+ COALESCE(f3,''))
```

Well when I insert this into my column it adds new columns and update just fails.  Is there a way to update a value inside MS SQL and use it to change a value?

Thanks

```
update dbo.tblGeoTable (CombinedEmail)
select (COALESCE(f1,'')+';'+ COALESCE(f2,'')+';'+ COALESCE(f3,'')) 
from dbo.tblGeoTable
```

Here is the data

F1 = f1email@email.com
F2 = f2email@email.com
F3 = f3email@email.com
CombinedEmail = f1+f2+f3, but I need the ; in there to seperate them and I need it replaced in the current row that its in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want try this

```
UPDATE tblGeoTable
   SET CombinedEmail = COALESCE(f1,'')+';'+ COALESCE(f2,'')+';'+ COALESCE(f3,'')
```

Here is **[sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93224/1)**

EDIT:

If you want to add instead of replace to the values in CombinedEmail column you can do

```
UPDATE tblGeoTable
   SET CombinedEmail = COALESCE(CombinedEmail,'') + ';' + COALESCE(f1,'')+';'+ COALESCE(f2,'')+';'+ COALESCE(f3,'')
```

Comment: I can do this already, but I need to be able to update my current table column with information thats already there

Comment: You mean you want `CombinedEmail=CombinedEmail+f1+f2+f3`?

Comment: @Intelwalk If not than please provide (in your original question)  a couple of rows of sample data and how you want your output to look like.

Comment: @Intelwalk That's exactly what my original answer does. Assuming that f1, f2, f3 and CombinedEmail are columns it populates values of CombinedEmail from values of f1, f2, f3 combined. Did you see sqlfiddle example that I provided? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Nope your right!  Thanks!  I had an amalgam of insert into/select state and my update statement! DOH!  Thanks for the help!